# JQuery function binded to click event of body node with another click event executed immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, bind

```
$().ready(function(){
    $("#move-to").click(function(){
        $("body").bind("click",function(){
            alert("foo");
        });
    }); 
});
```

Why I see alert("foo") immediately after click on "move-to"?
When I bind "alert" on some div in document evrithing is ok.
Can come somebady help?
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: because `#move-to` click is being propagated to `body` element. It's called event propagation in JS.

Comment: You really shouldn't be binding click events inside of click events (unless your usecase is an edgecase i guess)

Comment: @KevinB: That can be useful for popup menus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your `#move-to` handler runs, the click event bubbles up to the `<body>`, firing the handler you just bound.

You can prevent that by calling `e.stopPropagation()`.

Alternatively, you can bind the `<body>` click event after this event cycle by moving the `bind()` to a `setTimeout` call.

Answer (score 0):

```
$().ready(function(){
    $("#move-to").click(function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
      $("body").bind("click",function(){
       alert("foo");
      });      
    }); 
});
```

But I think you code bind the click event again and again when you click on `#move-to`, this is not good if you don't unbind that click event somewhere else.

Comment: Yes of course. There will be unbind in function. It's only simple variant of function.